# how to start the dropdown from the border of the menu bar instead of showing directly below the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/13/) for the menu-header section for my webpage. I have made it by seeing this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwljf.png). Once I click `PROGRAMS` and `WORLD OF NORTHMAN`, it should dropdown and show elements but it should only start the dropdown from the border of that header and that is I am not able to make it work.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><b>PROGRAMS</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><b>WORLD OF NORTHMAN</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#"><i>BE EXTRODINARY</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>RISK &amp; REWARD</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>BLOG</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>OUR STORY</i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that dropdown starts from the border of that menu instead coming directly from each of those text?

Comment: give it a margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `margin-top: 14px` to the `.topnav ul > li > ul` selector:

```
.topnav ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f76c38;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/15/

As a plus, if you want to close other opened menus: https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/16/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the padding to `.topnav a` rather than `.topnav ul > li`. https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/14/. This is because the `ul` html tag sits below the `a` html tag. If you want to keep the `background-color` the same size, use margin for the `a` tag, instead of `padding`, but I think it looks better with padding in my opinion :)

EDIT: Updated fiddle with `inline-block` image and navigation. https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/19/. This should get you close to what you want. The rest is up to you. Happy Coding.

Comment: ok cool.. also how can I align them in one line just like they are in my image? Right now they are coming below the image. I need to exactly replicate what I have in my image. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean you want them to appear from under the cloud image? If so you will need to play around with the `z-index` of `.topnav ul > li > ul`.

Comment: no no .. look at my original image I have in the question.. image and those two drop down appear in one line right? but in your jsffiddle, those two drop down text appear just below the image.. I want all these three to appear in one line. Basically I want to exactly replicate the way it is there in my image.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
.dropdown-content{ margin-top:14px; }
```